# System.MissingMemberException when adding image to Excel through VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Currently I'm trying to add a diagram/picture to an Excel file through VB.NET. When researching how, I often saw the format `excelapplication.worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(picture path)`. I'm trying to use this (with a bit of modification) but I keep running into the error:

> System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Shapes' on type 'Range' not found.'

In my code below you can see that I have a particular cell I want to add the image to. Just incase it was narrowing down what cells I wanted in was what was causing my issues, I tried removing `Range("AU6")` and the error was basically the same except now Shapes isn't a member of ApplicationClass.

> System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Shapes' on type 'ApplicationClass' not found.'

Here's my code:

```
MyExcel.Workbooks.Open(LoadDir & FileName.Text)
        MyExcel.Sheets("Sheet1").activate()

        MyExcel.Range("AL6").Activate() 
        MyExcel.Range("AL6").Value = Proj_Desc.Text

        MyExcel.Range("AU6:BA46").Activate()
        MyExcel.Range("AU6").Shapes.AddPicture(Proj_DiagramPath.Text) 'Error Appears Here

MyExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
        MyExcel.Quit()

        Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MyExcel.Workbooks)
```

Comment: The `Shapes` property is a “WORKSHEET” property. The current code is trying to use the `Shape` property from a `Range`… which obviously will not work.

Comment: Oh alright. If that's the case, will I get away with inserting the picture into the desired cells only by using ```MyExcel.Range("AU6").Activate()```? Btw, thank you for getting back to me!

Comment: From my understanding, `Shapes` are external and are laid on top of the existing cell(s), and you cannot specifically place a shape “into” a cell. Once you have a `Shape` object in the worksheet you can use it’s `Placement` property to set the way the shape object is attached to the cells below it. MS [XlPlacement Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlplacement?view=excel-pia) … my understanding is that whatever cell(s) the picture is lying above are the cell(s) that will be used when the shapes `Placement` property is set.